# Git me vuelve a pedir la contraseña en Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, git, github, vscode, ssh

Hace poco creé un repositorio en github y en mi computador generé mi respectiva clave SSH. El problema es de que cada cierto tiempo me aparece una ventana que me vuelve a pedir la "passphrase", la escribo y después de poco tiempo me la vuelve a pedir. Ya se volvió desesperante.

Comment: Te sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para adaptarte mejor a esta plataforma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Puedes hacer uso del helper de credential, store

git config credential.helper store

> Para la config general de username y password se alamacena en ~/.git-credentials toma en cuenta que la configuración global afecta si lo haces --global estará disponible en todos los repositorios, tal cual como funcionan los comandos globales de .bin en unix

```
git config user.name " Tu nombre "
git config user.email " Email@ejemplo.com "
git config user.password " tu contraseña "
```

> y para hacerlos global solo agrega antes de user.XXX el flag --global y asi estará disponible en todos los repositorios

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de solucionarlo es usar los [credentials helpers de Github](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)

Puedes hacerlo escribiendo en la terminal:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Por defecto, son 15 minutos lo que guarda tus credenciales, puedes cambiarlo a lo que tu quieras (el tiempo es en segundos) con el argumento `--timeout`, en este caso yo lo fijo en una semana.

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=604800'
```

### Nota

Ten en cuenta los riesgos de seguridad que esto conlleva, en distintos caso, virus, que compartas PC, etc.